# Java API with which I can manipulate and modify HTML code and its tags?

Tags: java, html, css, api, image

Is there a 3rd party API for the sole purpose with which I can replace relative URLs in the source HTML and CSS into absolute URLs, keeping in mind the fact that the source contains a mix of relative and absolute URLs. For those thinking twice about this question, the `String` Object's `replaceAll()` method has some shortcomings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TagSoup](http://mercury.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) to parse the HTML and then use standard XPath expressions to get all your links and img tags.

Comment: +10! citate: "a SAX-compliant parser written in Java that, instead of parsing well-formed or valid XML, parses HTML as it is found in the wild"

Comment: @ chiborg I'm a total noob to XML Parsing, could you give me an example as to how to parse HTML code contained in a 'String' object, and then retrieving all the relative URLs, following which, converting them into absolute URL where, the host-name is specified in a String Object.